# [] + []; { } +[]; [] + {}; {} + {}; Why only 2 errors in Typescript 3.6?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript will try to protect you from portions of JavaScript that never worked (Basarat - Typescript Deep Dive)

```
[] + [];// TS error
{ } +[];// OK, why?
[] + {};// TS error
{} + {};// OK, why?
```

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected:

`console.log([] + []);// TS error
console.log({} +[]); // TS error
console.log([] + {});// TS error
console.log({} +{});// TS error`

I think problem was: { } - empty block statement, 
                    {}  - empty object